# How to navigate out of draft view

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-drafts

When accessing a topic you have edited, through the "achievements" (rep) dropdown at the top of the page, it shows you the proposed changes view. Kind of like edit history, but only for your edit.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/41052?draftId=35955

[image]

Clicking on the title of a topic from there almost brings you back to the normal view, where you can vote up and down on examples, but it's like a pseudo-editing mode with an adjustable-size read-only area on the bottom... preview-mode?

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/980/polymorphism?draftId=35955

[image]

**Note:** If you instead click the "this topic" link here, you can navigate back to the topic, as seen in [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329942/4957418). If you click the title, as described above, the "this topic" link disappears.

The only way I can see of going back to the topic is by deleting the `draftId` parameter from the URL (took a while to find that), or by going back to the `Documentation` home page and searching for the topic from there.

**How do you navigate out of the above preview-mode?**