# How to navigate to a documentation topic from a draft

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-drafts

I saw the following link in chat and followed it

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/60460

I made a comment on the changes and the change was subsequently rejected.

When I click on the topic title on that page it takes me to the following page

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/drafts/51005

Which is the rejected change not the topic

How can I get to the actual topic?

I've seen [How to navigate out of draft view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329406/how-to-navigate-out-of-draft-view) but it seems to be more about the editors point of view rather than a reader/reviewer

Comment: I just got the tumbleweed badge for my question. It is slightly different from yours, as this answer didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click the *this topic* link at the very top to get to the plain topic.

[image: topic link screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I actually just noticed that myself, and i was coming back here to delete the question until I saw your answer.